# How to customize the css (position) of the google sign-in popup?

Tags: jquery, drupal-8

I am coding for a *drupal-8* application and using *jquery* for front end, I have Google drive popup and it is not vertically/horizontally centrally aligned for "1920 x 1080" resolution.

I need to align the popup in the center for the resolution "1920 x 1080".
Using *gapi* auth or *jquery* because my front end is based on *jquery*.

Comment: Where's your current code? How should anybody provide help if you don't show what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we center a div using JQUERY simply creating a function of center and calling on divs.

```js
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent) {
    if (parent) {
        parent = this.parent();
    } else {
        parent = window;
    }
    this.css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
        "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });
return this;
}
$("div.target:nth-child(1)").center(true);
$("div.target:nth-child(2)").center(false);
```

```css
div.container{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #555;
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}

div.target{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    color:white;
    background:rgba(30,30,30,.7);
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="target">1<br>Your Google Form</div>

</body>
```